# Why doesen't it clear screen in if method (C language only)

Tags: c, syntax, command, conio

I was trying to make a shell interpreter similar to DOS in C language (for fun obviously)

And when i type clear, as shown in the code below it should make it so it clears the screen. But it doesn't.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    char command[128];
    int loop = 0;
    void main(){
        clrscr();
        printf("Starting shell\n");
        clrscr();
        while ( loop == 0){
            printf("command:");
            scanf("%s", &command);
            if(command=='clear'){
                printf("Clearing screen");
                clrscr();
            }  

/** Other Code **/
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", command); if(!strcmp(command, "clear")){ printf("Clearing screen"); clrscr(); }`

Comment: Lots of basic C errors here. Read the documentation on these functions and do some C tutorials. Use `scanf("%s", command)` and `if(!strcmp(command, "clear"))`. Strings in C use double quotes, not single.

Comment: _Don't_ use `scanf("%s", command)` but `fgets(command, sizeof commmand, stdin)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(command=='clear')
```

it's not valid string comparison. use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) to compare string in `C`.

It should be

```
if (!strcmp(command, "clear"))
{
   printf("Clearing screen");
   clrscr();
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that `'clear'` isn't a valid C string.